# Can "duration" mean "remainder"?

Tags: word-choice

On multiple commercial domestic flights, I've heard a flight attendant make an announcement just before final descent back to the ground that "the seat belt sign will remain illuminated for the *duration* of the flight."

This strikes me as an obvious mistake, where clearly "remainder" is intended. Is there an argument for using "duration" in this instance, despite much of the flight having already been spent with the seat belt sign dark?

Comment: I think this looks like a peeve.

Comment: *Duration* means "duration". There is nothing about the word that says whether the entirety of it is in the future or in the past, or if you're in the middle of it. Plus she's already has a *remain* in there. Do you really suggest she said the lights would *remain* illuminated for the *remainder* of the flight?

Comment: ***The*** _duration_ is an idiom, and includes _the remaining duration_ by convention.

Comment: "The seat belt sign will remain illuminated for the rest / remainder of the flight" certainly sounds semantically preferable, but 'how something looks / sounds' tends to be considered of greater importance than - well, most other things. Just accept 'the duration' as a substitute for 'the time the flight lasts from now'.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm taking the upshot of your statement as "this question is not worthy of asking or answering", but I'm wondering if you might go into a little more detail about why that is. Before reading the responses, I firmly believed that "duration" could never refer to a part of a larger span of time without that smaller part being specified. Is your objection just that if one is already aware of the nuance, this seems like someone making a quibbling point rather than an earnest inquiry?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't *... for the **remaining** duration of the flight*? Also, was the speaker a native English speaker? If not maybe he/she made a mistake.

Comment: @ Tyler: Well, in the specific context as given, it's obvious what the flight attendant *means*. Suppose she'd said *"Please remain seated for the duration of your journey"*? Would you quibble over how you were expected to actually get to your seat? (assuming you count your journey as starting at or before boarding). For all I know, the airline has conducted tests, and discovered that passengers are less likely to unbuckle their belts prematurely if the attendant says *duration* rather than *remainder* (I'd be more than prepared to believe that, actually! :)

Comment: ...to a first approximation, *words* don't have "meanings" - meaning is an attribute of *usages in context*.

Comment: Please leave feedback with down votes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although from the definition of [duration](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duration) you would appear to be correct:-

1. Continuance or persistence in time.
2. A period of existence or persistence: sat quietly through the duration of the speech.
3. The number of years required to receive the present value of future payments, both of interest and principle, of a bond, often used as an indicator of a bond's price volatility resulting from changes in interest rates.

the word often appears in the phrase *for the duration of the war* ([here](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/ForDura.shtml) and [here](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/ForDura.shtml)),  by which is strictly meant *the whole of the war*. But this usage refers to a state of affairs that wasn't the case at the start of the war, and so means the remainder.

For instance, someone conscripted into the army *for the duration of the war* would seldom have been conscripted at the start of the war.

Comment: The definition I looked at specified that this sense was restricted to uses *without* "of" after "duration", but I suppose this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If the flight attendant were to say "the seatbelt sign will NOW remain on for the duration of the flight" it would make more sense in the context of the remainder.  Remainder is not an attractive word unless referring to something mathematical.  In Britain they just say "the sign will now be illuminated for the rest of the flight."